# PayPal BuyNow button as ShoppingCart submit button

Tags: paypal, payment

We have a web site which sales digital subscriptions using PayPal BuyNow button. We are planning to release a second web site which is “Grocery Store Online” site with our proprietary shopping cart in it. We would like to re-use already implemented BuyNow button functionality.

Would it be OK with PayPal if we treat a Shopping Cart as “one aggregated product” with ProductID being our CartID, ProductName being “Shopping Cart Order with 5 Items …”, CartTotal being AmountToPay and so on and connect it to BuyNow button functionality?

Are there any ***PayPal imposed limitations*** against above approach? 
We are aware of PayPal’s ShoppingCart functionality but want to keep things simple.

Answer (score 0):

PayPal supports third party cart use case. Please refer following documentation it should answer some of your questions:

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/cart_upload/

Comment: Thank you for your response Vinay. We are aware of 3rd party shopping cart support in PayPal. Our question is - "Do we really need shopping cart functionality here ? All discounts, taxes and shipping cost was already calculated in our side. All what we need is to submit the payment and get it processed"

Comment: Then I believe you treat your shopping cart checkout as "Buy Now" button internally. As long as you are able to map all your data (amount, item etc) to "Buy Now" variables it should work.

Test this once to be sure you are fine with the Buyer experience on PayPal side when you treat cart as "Buy Now".